# Problema con Operacion logica

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo 2 INPUT A y B, ambos reciben el resultado de una multiplicación entre X y Y y las sumatoria de N veces los inputs que el usuario desee agregar respectivamente.

Tengo este codigo.

```
function suma(){
var A = document.getElementById("total");
var B = document.getElementById("subTotal");

resultado = parseInt(A.value) - parseInt(B.value);
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

Que me suma perfectamente los inputs A y B para poder hallar C en un div pero siempre y cuando yo de click en alguno lo cual es correcto pero lo que yo busco es que se actualice de manera automática. 
Dejo una imagen como referencia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este codigo hallo la sumatoria de B

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#checkAll', function() {           
    $(".itemRow").prop("checked", this.checked);
}); 
$(document).on('click', '.itemRow', function() {    
    if ($('.itemRow:checked').length == $('.itemRow').length) {
        $('#checkAll').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
});  
var count = $(".itemRow").length;
$(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() { 
    count++;
    var htmlRows = '';
    htmlRows += '<tr>';
    htmlRows += '<td style="text-align: center;"><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td style="text-align: center;"><input type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>'; 
    htmlRows += '<td style="text-align: center;">S/. <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+count+'" value="1" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td style="text-align: center;"><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+count+'" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" name="total[]" id="total_'+count+'" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></td>';       
    htmlRows += '</tr>';
    $('#invoiceItem').append(htmlRows);
}); 
$(document).on('click', '#removeRows', function(){
    $(".itemRow:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
    calculateTotal();
});     
$(document).on('blur', "[id^=quantity_]", function(){
    calculateTotal();
}); 
$(document).on('blur', "[id^=price_]", function(){
    calculateTotal();
}); 
$(document).on('blur', "#taxRate", function(){      
    calculateTotal();
}); 
$(document).on('blur', "#amountPaid", function(){
    var amountPaid = $(this).val();
    var totalAftertax = $('#totalAftertax').val();  
    if(amountPaid && totalAftertax) {
        totalAftertax = totalAftertax-amountPaid;           
        $('#amountDue').val(totalAftertax);
    } else {
        $('#amountDue').val(totalAftertax);
    }   
}); 
$(document).on('click', '.deleteInvoice', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(confirm("")){
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{id:id, action:'delete_invoice'},              
            success:function(response) {
                if(response.status == 1) {
                    $('#'+id).closest("tr").remove();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
}); 

function calculateTotal(){
    var totalAmount = 0; 
    $("[id^='price_']").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.replace("price_",'');
        var price = $('#price_'+id).val();
        var quantity  = $('#quantity_'+id).val();
        if(!quantity) {
            quantity = 1;
        }
        var total = price*quantity;
        $('#total_'+id).val(parseFloat(total));
        totalAmount += total;           
    });
    $('#subTotal').val(parseFloat(totalAmount));    
    var taxRate = $("#taxRate").val();
    var subTotal = $('#subTotal').val();    
    if(subTotal) {
        var taxAmount = subTotal*taxRate/100;
        $('#taxAmount').val(taxAmount);
        subTotal = parseFloat(subTotal)+parseFloat(taxAmount);
        $('#totalAftertax').val(subTotal);      
        var amountPaid = $('#amountPaid').val();
        var totalAftertax = $('#totalAftertax').val();  
        if(amountPaid && totalAftertax) {
            totalAftertax = totalAftertax-amountPaid;           
            $('#amountDue').val(totalAftertax);
        } else {        
            $('#amountDue').val(subTotal);
        }
    }
}
```

Es un codigo que estoy reutilizando de un proyecto anterior.
Y este seria mi codigo html

```
<div class="col-6">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="codigo" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Nombre de Proveedor</label>
                                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomProveedor" name="nomProveedor" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>  
                                                        <div class="col-12"style="padding-top: 7px;">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="codigo" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Peso de Materia Prima</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-12 inputs">
                                                                            <input type="number" min="-999" max="999" id="x" class="inputs_valors_privisionales form-control" value="0" type="number">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>  
                                                                </div>      
                                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="codigo" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Precio</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                            <input type="number" min="-999" max="999" id="y" class="inputs_valors_privisionales form-control" value="0" type="number">
                                                                            
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>              
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <table class="table table-hover" id="invoiceItem">  
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th><center><input id="checkAll" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"></center></th>
                                                                <th><center>Gastos a Pagar</center></th>
                                                                <th><center>Moneda</center></th>
                                                                <th><center>Monto Destinatario</center></th>    
                                                            </tr>                           
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td><center><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></center></td>
                                                                <td><center><input type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></center></td>
                                                                <td><center>S/. <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" value="1" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></center></td>
                                                                <td><center><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></center></td>
                                                            </tr>                       
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>                                              
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-secondary delete" id="removeRows" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Borrar</button>
                                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addRows" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Agregar Más</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <label class="control-label float-right" style="padding-top: 9px;">Gastos Total</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3 float-right">
                                                            <div class="grupo">
                                                                <input value="" type="number" style="text-align: right;" class="inputs_valors_privisionales2 form-control" name="subTotal" id="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal" readonly onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}"   >
                                                                <input class="form-control inputs_valors_privisionales2" id="total"readonly onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}" name="subTotal2">             
                                                                <input type="text" id="c" value="0">                                                                
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Comment: ¿De manera automática cuando suceda qué? ¿Cuando cambie el contenido del `<input>` A o el del B? ¿Cuando cargue la página? El automático no existe en programación, todo atiende a acción/reacción.

Comment: phpMyGuel, gracias por responder tendre en cuenta lo ultimo que me dijiste.
Quiero que se actualice cuando A y B resivan algun resultado sin que yo de clic en alguno de esos dos

Comment: ¿Y cómo recibirían los input A y B dichos resultados? ¿Los introduce el propio usuario? ¿Llegan de una llamada AJAX y se rellenan desde Javascript...?

Comment: No, a y b solo resiven resultados de X*Y y la sumatoria de N respectivamente. El usuario solo llena los campos X, Y y N

Comment: Entonces necesitas asignar un evento `change` sobre los `<input>` X e Y para que cuando el valor de estos cambie, actualizar A y B y lanzar el cálculo de C.

Comment: Eso ya lo tengo hecho, A y B me calcula cuando ingreso numeros a X, Y y N. Pero cuando A y B resive datos yo tengo que dar clic sobre uno de ellos para que se actualice C y eso es lo que yo no quiero.

Comment: Porque lo que tienes que hacer es después de calcular A y B, e insertar sus valores en el HTML, lanzar tu función `suma()` ya que ya tendrías los valores necesarios para calcular C.

Comment: Creo que aqui no está claro lo que se pregunta,  la información que aportas es insuficiente, por favor, visita https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Te sugiero, por ejemplo, que incluyas un ejemplo minimo verificable.

Comment: phpMyGuel, ajaaa así es y si me calcula pero como te repito solo cuando yo de clic sobre uno de ellos apesar de que están en readonly y eso es lo que quiero evitar. Osea quiero que C se genere cuando A y B reciba datos sin que yo de clic en uno de ellos porque para ello mejor pongo un botón que diga calcular o generar y ya y eso quiero omitirlo

Answer (score 0):

En mis comentarios te trataba de explicar que hicieras algo similar a esto:

```js
$(function () {
  //Asignamos los eventos change a los input Y y X 
  //que son los que lanzan todo el cálculo.
  $('#x').on('change', calculo);
  $('#y').on('change', calculo);
});

function calculo () {
  let x = $('#x');
  let y = $('#y');
  let a = $('#a');
  let b = $('#b');
  
  //Me invento las operaciones para calcular A y B, 
  //aquí tendrías tú que definir las que necesites.
  a.val(parseInt(x.val()) + 10);
  b.val(parseInt(y.val()) + 5);
  
  //Ahora que tenemos los input A y B rellenos podemos lanzar tu función suma
  //para rellenar C.
  suma();
}

function suma(){
  let a = $('#a');
  let b = $('#b');
  let c = $('#c');
  let resultado = parseInt(a.val()) - parseInt(b.val());
  
  c.val(resultado);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>X: </label>
<input type="text" id="x" value="0">
<label>Y: </label>
<input type="text" id="y" value="0">
<br>
<br>
<label>A: </label>
<input type="text" id="a" value="0">
<label>B: </label>
<input type="text" id="b" value="0">
<label>C: </label>
<input type="text" id="c" value="0">
```

Haciendo que el cálculo de C se haga en la misma función que el cálculo de A y B conseguirías que todo el proceso se ejecutase cuando X o Y cambien.

Comment: phpMyGuel, aplique tu ejemplo a lo que quiero hacer y este fue el resultado
https://prnt.sc/tl97v5

Comment: El NaN lo obtienes porque seguramente la operación para obtener el valor de C no esté realizada correctamente. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es seguir la recomendación de @Fernando Carrascosa y que subas el código con el que obtienes el contenido de X, Y y N para calcular y actualizar los campos A y B. De esa manera podremos ver donde estás teniendo el problema.

Comment: phpMyGuel edite la pregunta, espero puedas ayudarme.